# PL/SQL failing with error code ORA-01858

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that is failing at this level:

```
select trunc(sysdate - TO_DATE(STARTING_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) into DAYS_NBR from dual;
```

where STARTING_DATE is an input date that is the of the format DD/MM/YYYY. 
Here is the error code

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

could you please check.

Comment: How are you sure this line caused it?

Comment: If `STARTING_DATE` is of data type date, you do not need to cast it to a date.  This certainly could be an issue.

Comment: What is data type of `STARTING_DATE` - `DATE` or `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: because I've done a step over debug line by line in Toad for oracle.

Comment: @Patrick: STARTING_DATE is of type VARCHAR2

Comment: Then for sure, the input date is not in the format 'DD/MM/YYYY'.. Try printing the value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Giorgi Orvelashvili has stated, the starting_date is a varchar2 and the format mask which is being entered does not correspond with the 
format that you are anticipating.  Here is a reproduction of your error:

```
    APPS@tst> --varchar
    APPS@erptst> DECLARE
      2    starting_date VARCHAR2(30) := to_char( SYSDATE -5,'MON/DD/YYYY') ;
      3    days_nbr      NUMBER;
      4  BEGIN
      5    SELECT trunc(SYSDATE - to_date(starting_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
      6    INTO days_nbr
      7    FROM dual;
      8    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(days_nbr));
      9  END;

 10  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

The way to correct this is to declare starting_date as a date and then there will be no need to use the to_date casting function:

```
    APPS@tst>  --date
    APPS@tst> DECLARE
      2    starting_date DATE:= SYSDATE -5;
      3    days_nbr      NUMBER;
      4  BEGIN
      5    SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE - starting_date) INTO days_nbr FROM dual;
      6    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(days_nbr));
      7  END;
      8  /

5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

STARTING_DATE unable to convert correct date format. Check on which value of STARTING_DATE does your code return this error.

Answer (score -1):

MedAli, try compare your date masks, may be clue is here ?

```
DECLARE
 starting_date VARCHAR2(30) := to_char( SYSDATE -5,'MON/DD/YYYY') ;
BEGIN
```

...

```
SELECT trunc(SYSDATE - to_date(starting_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))...
END;
```

BTW, in general, you can use standard format, e.g. DATE '2015-12-31'